NO SE ABREN MODALS LUEGO DE UNA BUSQUEDA DINAMICA
Estoy haciendo un catálogo de productos para mi página web.
El catálogo está compuesto por productos y cada producto al presionar click en él abre su respectivo modal de manera correcta.
El problema se presenta luego de realizar una búsqueda dinámica en la que los productos se generan nuevamente en el DOM y yo al presionar click en el producto generado por así decir no abre el modal que antes de hacer una búsqueda SI abría.
Probé asignando los eventos a los botones ver-mas pero tampoco funciona.
Creí que era problema de los data-target que no están correctamente asignados pero inspeccioné los elementos y sí tienen el ID correcto.
En otras versiones del código puse logs para ver si se generaban los modal o los botones y sí, eso se genera correctamente.
El problema parece estar en que no existe el evento "click" sobre los botones ver-mas luego de hacer una búsqueda.
Adjunto el código:
<script>
const itemsPerPage = 80;
const totalItems = productos.length;
const totalPages = Math.ceil(totalItems / itemsPerPage);

let currentPage = getPageFromURL();

function getPageFromURL() {
    const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    const page = parseInt(urlParams.get('page'));
    return isNaN(page) ? 1 : page;
}

function updateURL() {
    const url = new URL(window.location);
    url.searchParams.set('page', currentPage);
    window.history.pushState({}, '', url);
}

function eliminarTildes(str) {
    return str.normalize('NFD').replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, "");
}

function buscarProductos() {
    const query = eliminarTildes(document.getElementById('search-input').value.toLowerCase());

    if (query === '') {
        window.location.search = '?page=1';
        return;
    }

    const palabrasBusqueda = query.split(' ').filter(palabra => palabra.trim() !== '');

    const resultados = productos.filter(producto => {
        const nombre = eliminarTildes(producto.nombre.toLowerCase());
        const descripcion = eliminarTildes(producto.descripcion.toLowerCase());

        return palabrasBusqueda.every(palabra =>
            nombre.includes(palabra) || descripcion.includes(palabra)
        );
    });

    if (resultados.length > 0) {
        renderCatalogo(resultados, true);
    } else {
        const catalogo = document.getElementById('catalogo');
        catalogo.innerHTML = '<p>No se encontraron resultados para la búsqueda.</p>';
    }
}

document.getElementById('search-input').addEventListener('keypress', function (event) {
    if (event.key === 'Enter') {
        buscarProductos();
    }
});

function renderCatalogo(productosMostrar, esBusqueda = false) {
    const catalogo = document.getElementById('catalogo');
    catalogo.innerHTML = '';

    productosMostrar.forEach(producto => {
        const divProducto = document.createElement('div');
        divProducto.classList.add('producto');

        const img = document.createElement('img');
        img.src = producto.imagen;
        img.alt = producto.nombre;

        const divContent = document.createElement('div');
        divContent.classList.add('producto-content');

        const h2 = document.createElement('h2');
        h2.textContent = producto.nombre;

        const p = document.createElement('p');
        p.textContent = producto.descripcion;

        const button = document.createElement('button');
        button.classList.add('ver-mas');
        button.setAttribute('data-target', producto.modal);
        button.textContent = 'Ver más';

        divContent.appendChild(h2);
        divContent.appendChild(p);
        divContent.appendChild(button);

        divProducto.appendChild(img);
        divProducto.appendChild(divContent);

        catalogo.appendChild(divProducto);
    });

    if (!esBusqueda) {
        updatePagination();
    } else {
        document.getElementById('pagination').innerHTML = '';
    }

    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
}

function changePage(direction) {
    currentPage += direction;
    if (currentPage < 1) currentPage = 1;
    if (currentPage > totalPages) currentPage = totalPages;

    updateURL();
    location.reload();
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
}

function goToPage(page) {
    currentPage = page;
    updateURL();
    location.reload();
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
}

function updateCatalog() {
    const startIndex = (currentPage - 1) * itemsPerPage;
    const endIndex = Math.min(startIndex + itemsPerPage, totalItems);
    const productosMostrar = productos.slice(startIndex, endIndex);

    renderCatalogo(productosMostrar);
}

function updatePagination() {
    const pagination = document.getElementById('pagination');
    pagination.innerHTML = '';

    const prevButton = document.createElement('button');
    prevButton.id = 'prev';
    prevButton.textContent = 'Anterior';
    prevButton.disabled = currentPage === 1;
    prevButton.onclick = () => changePage(-1);
    pagination.appendChild(prevButton);

    for (let i = 1; i <= totalPages; i++) {
        const pageButton = document.createElement('button');
        pageButton.textContent = i;
        pageButton.classList.add('page-button');
        if (i === currentPage) pageButton.classList.add('active');
        pageButton.onclick = () => goToPage(i);
        pagination.appendChild(pageButton);
    }

    const nextButton = document.createElement('button');
    nextButton.id = 'next';
    nextButton.textContent = 'Siguiente';
    nextButton.disabled = currentPage === totalPages;
    nextButton.onclick = () => changePage(1);
    pagination.appendChild(nextButton);
}

updateCatalog();

<script>
document.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    if (event.target.classList.contains('ver-mas')) {
        const modalId = event.target.getAttribute('data-target');
        const modal = document.getElementById(modalId);
        if (modal) {
            modal.style.display = 'block';
            document.body.classList.add('modal-open');
        }
    }

    if (event.target.classList.contains('close')) {
        const modal = event.target.closest('.modal');
        if (modal) {
            modal.style.display = 'none';
            document.body.classList.remove('modal-open');
        }
    }

    if (event.target.classList.contains('modal')) {
        event.target.style.display = 'none';
        document.body.classList.remove('modal-open');
    }
});

<script>
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    const modalContainer = document.getElementById("modal-container");

    modales.forEach(modal => {
        const modalElement = document.createElement("div");
        modalElement.id = modal.id;
        modalElement.className = "modal";
        modalElement.innerHTML = `
                                <div class="modal-content">
                                    <div class="modal-header">
                                        <h2>${modal.header}</h2>
                                        <span class="close">&times;</span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-body">
                                        <img src="${modal.image}" alt="${modal.header}">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-footer">
                                        <table>
                                            <tr>
                                                ${Object.keys(modal.rows[0]).map(key => `<th>${key}</th>`).join("")}
                                            </tr>
                                            ${modal.rows.map(row => `
                                                <tr>
                                                    ${Object.values(row).map(value => `<td>${value}</td>`).join("")}
                                                </tr>
                                            `).join("")}
                                        </table>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            `;
        modalContainer.appendChild(modalElement);
    });
});


Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla!

se ve tocho el código ... pero voy a estar dándole una mirada a ver en qué te puedo ayudar ... me llama la atención por el tema de DOM. estoy casi seguro que el problema esta relacionado a "delegates" algo que ocurria antes en jquery, pero pensaba que en javascrip vainilla no ocurria, como yo pase a programar en ES6+ no tengo estos problemas ...

necesito me indiques cual es la seccion de codigo que usar para atachear el listener a los botones: ver-mas evento "click"

@FranciscoIALover la sección del código que me consultas está en el segundo script, ahí se escucha el evento click en todo el documento, si el elemento clicado tiene la clase ver-mas, se obtiene el atributo data-target del botón, que contiene el ID del modal relacionado. Muchas gracias por la respuesta, estoy al tanto de cualquier consejo o recomendación!

ok mete ese script dentro de un método... y lo pones en dos lugares: cuando se carga el DOM y cuando se agregan nuevos elementos...

me confirmas si sabes como hacer ...

@FranciscoIALover si lo hice pero sigue sin funcionar, no sé si lo hice mal, por eso quisiera saber en dónde enviar el código que realice, gracias!!

me gusta codepen hay se me hace mas fácil ayudarte, solo tiene que agregar un ejemplo mínimo de html y el javascript relacionado... aqui puedes usar snipeds ... pero no se que tan facil sea para ti manejarlo...

@FranciscoIALover
https://codepen.io/pen?template=PwYJQZj
Ese es el link, faltaría colocar el CSS, algo de HTML y JS para que quede funcional pero lo que sería el script que me está fallando es ese de ahí. Gracias, estoy al tanto!

falta mucho no hay html no hay css, debe por lo menos llegar a hacer lo que describes que no hace ...
